# Addition of header changes layout in dash

Tags: python, html, css, plotly-dash, dashboard

I'm sure this is something super simple, but I'm trying to create a dashboard in python's dash. I have no prior experience in dash or html. I've managed to create div boxes in the layout I want, but when I add in a header to one of the div's, it completely destroys my layout (See attached screenshots). Can someone please help me understand where I've gone wrong?

[Dashboard before div](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ArTBf.png)

```
import dash
from dash import dcc
from dash import html
import pandas as pd
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output, State

app = dash.Dash()

app.layout = html.Div(
    
    [
        html.H1(
            children="ML Dashboard",
            className="main_title",
            style={
                "color": "black",
                "text-align": "center"
            },
        ),

        html.Div(
            [
                html.Div(
                    [
                       
                    ],
                    style={
                        "background-color": "#096484",
                        "height": "5vh",
                        "width": "20vw",
                        "margin-left": "9vw",
                    }
                ),
            ],
            style={
                "background-color": "#74B6CE",
                "height": "88vh",
                "width": "39vw",
                "margin-left": "1vw",
                "display": "inline-block"
            }
        ),

        html.Div(
            [

            ],
            style={
                "background-color": "#74B6CE",
                "height": "88vh",
                "width": "26vw",
                "margin-left": "1vw",
                "display": "inline-block"
            }
        ),

        html.Div(
            [
                html.Div(
                    [

                    ],
                    style={
                        "background-color": "#4796B3",
                        "height": "40vh",
                        "width": "24vw",
                        "margin-left": "1vw",
                        "margin-top": "3vh"
                    }
                ),

                html.Div(
                    [

                    ],
                    style={
                        "background-color": "#4796B3",
                        "height": "40vh",
                        "width": "24vw",
                        "margin-left": "1vw",
                        "margin-top": "1.5vh"
                    }
                ),

            ],
            style={
                "background-color": "#74B6CE",
                "height": "88vh",
                "width": "26vw",
                "margin-left": "1vw",
                "display": "inline-block"
            }
        ),

    ],
    style={
        "background-color": "#52ACCC",
        "height": "95vh",
        "width": "95vw",
        "margin-left": "2vw"
    }
)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(host='0.0.0.0', port=8080, debug=True)
```

[Dashboard after div](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cz4Nx.png)

```
import dash
from dash import dcc
from dash import html
import pandas as pd
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output, State

app = dash.Dash()

app.layout = html.Div(
    
    [
        html.H1(
            children="ML Dashboard",
            className="main_title",
            style={
                "color": "black",
                "text-align": "center"
            },
        ),

        html.Div(
            [
                html.Div(
                    [
                        html.H1(
                            children="PIPELINE",
                            className="title_1",
                            style={
                                "color": "white",
                                "text-align": "center"
                            },
                        ),
                    ],
                    style={
                        "background-color": "#096484",
                        "height": "5vh",
                        "width": "20vw",
                        "margin-left": "9vw",
                    }
                ),
            ],
            style={
                "background-color": "#74B6CE",
                "height": "88vh",
                "width": "39vw",
                "margin-left": "1vw",
                "display": "inline-block"
            }
        ),

        html.Div(
            [

            ],
            style={
                "background-color": "#74B6CE",
                "height": "88vh",
                "width": "26vw",
                "margin-left": "1vw",
                "display": "inline-block"
            }
        ),

        html.Div(
            [
                html.Div(
                    [

                    ],
                    style={
                        "background-color": "#4796B3",
                        "height": "40vh",
                        "width": "24vw",
                        "margin-left": "1vw",
                        "margin-top": "3vh"
                    }
                ),

                html.Div(
                    [

                    ],
                    style={
                        "background-color": "#4796B3",
                        "height": "40vh",
                        "width": "24vw",
                        "margin-left": "1vw",
                        "margin-top": "1.5vh"
                    }
                ),

            ],
            style={
                "background-color": "#74B6CE",
                "height": "88vh",
                "width": "26vw",
                "margin-left": "1vw",
                "display": "inline-block"
            }
        ),

    ],
    style={
        "background-color": "#52ACCC",
        "height": "95vh",
        "width": "95vw",
        "margin-left": "2vw"
    }
)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(host='0.0.0.0', port=8080, debug=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Exciting that you're getting started with Dash — it's an awesome web framework and the fact that it's all Python is a win-win; great way to get started.

Couple things though I'd point out:

1. I think you're going a little overboard with the nested `div`'s, unless you're absolutely attached to the exact style you have shared in your example, I'd recommend just using one main `Div` for the most part
2. It's a particular Dash-specific quirk that all CSS style keywords must be written in "camel case" (e.g. camelCase); so, actually none of your margin or any other style settings containing hyphens were actually being implemented/rendered

I've provided an example template you're free to use, which I've basically copy pasted and simplified down rather hastily from a work in progress open source github repo I'm working on called "[dash-webapp-template](https://github.com/jcollins-bioinfo/dash-webapp-template)"!

It looks like this, maybe this makes sense to you and you could use it as a jumping off point?

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cinzel:300,400,500,600,700|Muli:200,300,400,500,600|Open+Sans:200,300,400,500,600|Oswald:200,300,400,500,600&amp;subset=latin-ext');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:200,200i,300,300i,400,400i,500,500i');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:300,400,500,600,800&amp;subset=latin-ext');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Mono:200,300,400,500');

a { color: rgb(146, 146, 146); cursor: pointer; text-decoration: none; -o-transition: color 2.0s ease-out, background .1s ease-in; -ms-transition: color 2.0s ease-out, background .1s ease-in; -moz-transition: color 2.0s ease-out, background .1s ease-in; -webkit-transition: color 2.0s ease-out, background .1s ease-in; transition: all 1.67s ease-out; padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px }
a.fails { color: rgb(146, 146, 146); }
a.success { box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 20px 2px #96ffa2ab, 0px 0px 0px 4px rgb(165, 255, 200); border-radius: 18px; padding: 4px 50px 4px 10px; color: #147b01 !important; }
a.tool-ref { background: #dcdcdc4f; padding: 1px 3px 2px 3px; font-weight: 600; vertical-align: bottom; border-radius: 5px; color: rgb(35, 84, 148); border: 1px inset transparent }
a.tool-ref:hover { background: #fff; border: 1px outset #00ffc8; color: #3df5b4; text-decoration: underline }
a:hover, a:focus { color: #00efb8 !important; transition-duration: 2.75 s !important; transition-property: transform !important }
a:hover:before, a:focus:before, span:hover:before { pointer-events: none; position: absolute; z-index: -1; content: ''; opacity: .75; color: radial-gradient(ellipse at center, rgba(0, 0, 0, .11) 50 %, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.30) 90 %) !important; transition-duration: 1.5 s; transition-property: transform opacity 0.95 }
blockquote { border-left: 4px lightgrey solid; padding-left: 1rem; margin-top: 2rem; margin-bottom: 2rem; margin-left: 0rem }
body { font-size: 1.15rem; line-height: 1.1; font-weight: 400; font-family: "Oswald", "Muli", "Open Sans", "HelveticaNeue", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; color: rgb(50, 50, 50) }
body { margin: 0; overflow-x: hidden; text-align: center }
button#clear-pipeline { background-color: #cccccc24 !important; color: #000000bd !important; border: 2px outset; border-color: #d4d4d4a3; }
button#initiate-pipeline { font-size: 90%; padding: .67% 6% .67% 6%; border-width: 1px; margin: 2%; mix-blend-mode: color; letter-spacing: 8px; text-transform: uppercase; border-radius: 200px }
button#initiate-pipeline:hover { border-color: #00ffb54a; border-width: 0.5px; box-shadow: inset 0px -30px 0px -5px #efefef4a; background-blend-mode: exclusion; background: #ffffff5e; animation: pact-gradient-text-flow 5s infinite linear; }
button#refresh-downloads-links:hover { border: 2px inset #d9d9d921 }
button#sign-on-submit, button#log-out-submit, button#refresh-downloads-links, button.submit-buttons { background: rgb(65, 0, 255); mix-blend-mode: luminosity; margin-top: 1px; border: 2px outset #aaa; font-size: 60%; border-radius: 100px; letter-spacing: .5rem; display: inline-flex; }
button#sign-on-submit:hover, button#log-out-submit:hover, button.submit-buttons:hover { background-color: rgba(117, 117, 117, 0.5) !important; filter: invert(1) brightness(0.75) contrast(1.5) saturate(2) }
button, .button { margin-bottom: 0rem }
button, .button, button:focus { outline: none !important }
code { font-family: 'Roboto Mono', monospace; font-size: 0.85rem !important }
div.dash-spreadsheet, .dash-freeze-left, .dash-spreadsheet, .dash-spreadsheet-container, .dash-freeze-left, .dash-grow { max-width: 100% !important }
h1 { font-size: 3.5rem; font-family: 'Montserrat'; text-rendering: optimizeLegibility; color: #0d04a5; font-weight: 500; text-decoration: none; border-bottom: 0.0px solid gray; line-height: 4rem; text-decoration: underline }
h2 { font-family: 'Oswald', serif; color: var(--pph-color-8); cursor: default; font-weight: 300; font-size: 2rem; }
h3 { font-size: 2.0rem; font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif; font-weight: 300; color: rgb(32, 92, 188); cursor: default }
h4 { font-size: 1.5rem; font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif; color: var(--pph-color-57); font-weight: 400; cursor: default }
h5 { font-size: 1.2rem; font-family: 'Muli', sans-serif; cursor: default }
h6 { font-size: 1.1rem; color: #333; font-weight: 400 }
header.a:link { color: rgb(18, 116, 165) }
hr { margin-top: 2%; justify-content: center; margin-bottom: 3% }
hr { margin-top: 3rem; margin-bottom: 3.5rem; border-width: 0; border-top: 1px solid #E1E1E1 }
input, textarea, select, fieldset { margin-bottom: 0rem }
input:-internal-autofill-previewed, input:-internal-autofill-selected, textarea:-internal-autofill-previewed, textarea:-internal-autofill-selected, select:-internal-autofill-previewed, select:-internal-autofill-selected { background-color: #ffffff00 !important }
label, legend { display: block; margin-bottom: 0px }
label>.label-body { display: inline-block }
p { margin-top: 0 }
p, h2, h4, h5, h6 { margin-top: .5%; margin-bottom: 1% }
p, ul, ol { margin-bottom: 0.75rem }
pre, dl, figure, table, form { margin-bottom: 0rem }
section.wrapper { padding: 10px 0 }
span.menubar-title:hover { color: rgb(13, 4, 145) !important }

.button, button, input[type="submit"], input[type="reset"], input[type="button"] { display: inline-block; padding: 0 25px; color: #000000; text-align: center; font-size: 14px; font-weight: 500; font-family: "Cinzel", serif !important; line-height: 32px; text-decoration: none; white-space: nowrap; background-color: #ffffffcc !important; border-radius: 30px; border: 1px ridge #00000050; cursor: pointer; box-sizing: border-box }
.button.button-primary, button.button-primary, input[type="submit"].button-primary, input[type="reset"].button-primary, input[type="button"].button-primary { color: #00000075 !important; background-color: #33C3F050; border-color: #33C3F0 }
.button.button-primary:hover, button.button-primary:hover, input[type="submit"].button-primary:hover, input[type="reset"].button-primary:hover, input[type="button"].button-primary:hover, .button.button-primary:focus, button.button-primary:focus, input[type="submit"].button-primary:focus, input[type="reset"].button-primary:focus, input[type="button"].button-primary:focus { color: #00000075 !important; background-color: transparent; border-color: #1EAEDB }
.button:focus, button:focus, input[type="submit"]:focus, input[type="reset"]:focus, input[type="button"]:focus { color: #5C5D86; border-color: #00000075 !important }
.button:hover, button:hover, input[type="submit"]:hover, input[type="reset"]:hover, input[type="button"]:hover { border-color: #00FFC050; background: #00000075 }
.fader-line-long { display: flex; border: none; color: #fff0; height: 1px; background: -webkit-gradient(radial, 50% 50%, 0, 50% 50%, 650, from(rgba(200, 210, 220, 0.5)), to(#fff0)); }
.fader-line-short { display: flex; border: none; color: #fff0; height: 1px; background: -webkit-gradient(radial, 50% 50%, 0, 50% 50%, 350, from(rgba(120, 120, 150, 0.5)), to(#fff0)) }
.hr-style-2 { border-top: 3px double #8c8b8b; margin: 10px 10px 10px 10px; width: 67% }
.hvr-float-shadow, .workflow-css label { display: inline-block; vertical-align: middle; position: relative; -webkit-transition-duration: 1.0s; transition-duration: 1.0s; -webkit-transition-property: transform; transition-property: transform; text-rendering: optimizeLegibility }
.hvr-float-shadow:before, .workflow-css label:before { pointer-events: none; position: absolute; z-index: 99; content: ''; top: 180%; left: -10%; height: 6px; width: 120%; opacity: 0.05; background: -webkit-radial-gradient(center, ellipse, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 80%); background: radial-gradient(ellipse at center, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 80%); -webkit-transition-duration: 0.15s; transition-duration: 0.15s; -webkit-transition-property: transform, opacity; transition-property: transform, opacity }
.hvr-float-shadow:hover, .hvr-float-shadow:focus, .hvr-float-shadow:active, .workflow-css label:hover, .workflow-css label:focus, .workflow-css label:active { -webkit-transform: translateY(-1px)translateY(-1px); color: rgba(0, 215, 198, 1.0); opacity: 0.99; animation-name: anim-rainbow-flow-keys; animation-duration: 1s; animation-iteration-count: infinite; mix-blend-mode: hard-light }
.hvr-float-shadow:hover:before, .hvr-float-shadow:focus:before, .hvr-float-shadow:active:before, .workflow-css label:hover:before, .workflow-css label:focus:before, .workflow-css label:active:before { opacity: 0.9; -webkit-transform: translateY(-1px); transform: translateY(1px) }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

</head>

<body>
  <div>
    <h1>ML Dashboard</h1>
    <h2>PIPELINE</h2>
    <hr style="margin-left: 25%; width: 50%;">
    <h3 style="margin-top: -10px; text-align: center;">Step One: Upload [e.g., insert expected data input files].</h3>
    <h2 style="margin-top: -0.75%;">Then, click “Launch Pipeline” to launch analysis.</h2>
    <hr style="margin-left: 25%; width: 50%;">
    <div id="upload-data">
      <div class="" aria-disabled="false" style="position: relative;">
        <div style="background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5); border-color: transparent; border-radius: 100px; border-style: solid; border-width: 1px; box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 50, 0.16) 0px 1px 5px 2px; margin: 2% 15%; padding: 0.5%; text-align: center;">Drag/Drop ⤓ file(s) here —or—<a class="hvr-float-shadow" style="font-weight: 400; margin-bottom: 5px;"> Select from your computer</a>
          <h6 style="font-family: Cinzel, serif; font-size: 70%; letter-spacing: 1px; text-align: center;">(Other Info/Note)</h6>
          <h6 style="font-family: Cinzel, serif; letter-spacing: 4px; margin-top: -8px; text-align: center;">(...Note details / description...)</h6><span><h5 style="font-size: 80%; margin-left: 27.5%; width: 45%;">(Optional supplementary message...)</h5></span></div><input type="file" multiple="" autocomplete="off" style="position: absolute; inset: 0px; opacity: 1e-05; pointer-events: none;"></div>
    </div><br><br>
    <div style="position: relative; text-align: center;"><button class="hvr-float-shadow" id="initiate-pipeline">—Launch Pipeline—</button><br></div>
    <h5 id="pipeline-progress-disclaimer" style="color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); font-size: 0.85rem; margin-left: 22.5%; text-align: justify; width: 55%;">
      <div>
        <blockquote> ⚠ Cautionary notes / hints / advice / warnings - #1</blockquote>
      </div>
    </h5><br><button id="clear-pipeline">—Clear Current QC Results Output—</button><br></div>
</body>

</html>
```

```py
import dash
import pandas as pd

from dash import dcc
from dash import html
from dash.dependencies import Input
from dash.dependencies import Output
from dash.dependencies import State

app = dash.Dash()

app.layout = html.Div(
    [
        html.H1("ML Dashboard"),
        html.H2("PIPELINE"),
        html.Hr(style={"width": "50%", "marginLeft": "25%"}),
        html.H3(
            "Step One: Upload [e.g., insert expected data input files].",
            style={"textAlign": "center", "marginTop": "-10px"},
        ),
        html.H2(
            "Then, click “Launch Pipeline” to launch analysis.",
            style={"marginTop": "-0.75%"},
        ),
        html.Hr(style={"width": "50%", "marginLeft": "25%"}),
        dcc.Upload(
            id="upload-data",
            children=html.Div(
                [
                    "Drag/Drop ⤓ file(s) here    —or—",
                    html.A(
                        " Select from your computer",
                        className="hvr-float-shadow",
                        style={"fontWeight": "400", "marginBottom": "5px"},
                    ),
                    html.H6(
                        "(Other Info/Note)",
                        style={
                            "textAlign": "center",
                            "letterSpacing": "1px",
                            "fontFamily": "'Cinzel', serif",
                            "fontSize": "70%",
                        },
                    ),
                    html.H6(
                        "(...Note details / description...)",
                        style={
                            "textAlign": "center",
                            "letterSpacing": "4px",
                            "fontFamily": "'Cinzel', serif",
                            "marginTop": "-8px",
                        },
                    ),
                    html.Span(
                        html.H5(
                            "(Optional supplementary message...)",
                            style={
                                "width": "45%",
                                "marginLeft": "27.5%",
                                "fontSize": "80%",
                            },
                        )
                    ),
                ],
                style={
                    "borderWidth": "1px",
                    "borderStyle": "solid",
                    "borderRadius": "100px",
                    "textAlign": "center",
                    "margin": "2% 15%",
                    "boxShadow": "0px 1px 5px 2px rgba(0, 0, 50, 0.16)",
                    "borderColor": "transparent",
                    "padding": "0.5%",
                    "backgroundColor": "rgba(255,255,255,0.5)",
                },
            ),
            multiple=True,  # (Allow multiple files to be uploaded)
        ),
        html.Br(),
        html.Br(),
        html.Div(
            [
                html.Button(
                    "—Launch Pipeline—",
                    id="initiate-pipeline",
                    n_clicks=0,
                    className="hvr-float-shadow",
                ),
                html.Br(),
            ],
            style={"textAlign": "center", "position": "relative"},
        ),
        html.H5(
            html.Div(
                [
                    html.Blockquote(
                        " ⚠ Cautionary notes / hints / advice / warnings - #1"
                    ),
                ]
            ),
            style={
                "fontSize": "0.85rem",
                "color": "#00000080",
                "width": "55%",
                "marginLeft": "22.5%",
                "textAlign": "justify",
            },
            id="pipeline-progress-disclaimer",
        ),
        html.Br(),
        html.Button(
            "—Clear Current QC Results Output—",
            id="clear-pipeline",
            n_clicks=0,
        ),
        html.Br(),
    ]
)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run_server(
        host="0.0.0.0", port=8080, debug=True, dev_tools_hot_reload=True
    )
```

Here's the file structure following Dash docs recommended convention, and which I used here:

```sh
.
|-- [1.9K Nov 19 10:42]  app.py
`-- [  96 Nov 19 10:48]  assets
    `-- [ 24K Nov 19 11:02]  custom.css

1 directory, 3 files
```

where all the CSS in the SO in-answer HTML/CSS snippet CSS simply goes cutcopy into the custom.css file, specifically under a subdir called "assets" (which Dash is programmed to lookout for).